# \endhead text length affects longtable column width. How to avoid this?

Tags: longtable

The width of long table is affected by one of the line `\endhead`.  So if the actual table width was 2 inch based on the specs, but the `\endhead` text was longer than that, the last column stretches all the way to the right, even though it has say `p{.1in}`. An example will make this clear.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}   
   \begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.2in}|p{1in}|p{0.1in}|}\hline
   \# & ODE & A \\\hline
   \endfirsthead
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename \thetable {} -- second order series method. Regular singular point. Difference not integer. Continued from previous page}\\\hline 
   \# & ODE & A \\\hline
   \endhead \hline 
   \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{Continued on next page}\\\hline 
   \endfoot \hline 
   \endlastfoot      
   %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
\end{longtable}       
\end{document}
```

When compiled using `lualatex` gives

[image]

This is because the `\endhead` text is long.  Help says

> \endhead Specifies rows to appear at the top of every page.

I can make its fonts small. and this will help a little, like this, by changing the above one line to and adding `\scriptsize`, like this

```
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename \thetable {} -- {\scriptsize second order series method. Regular singular point. Difference not integer. Continued from previous page}}\\\hline
```

Now it compiles to

[image]

But the last column width is still not according to the `p` specification in the table.

The last column stretches to accommodate the text that should show up at top of each page in the long table.

So if this text is long (more descriptive), the last column will overflow to the right and does not look good.

Is there a way to make the text in `\endhead` not affect the width of the table and keep each column same width as given in the `p` format?

Here is an example from the real pdf with the actual table which has 10 columns.  The `\endhead` text is what shows at the top of the table on each page to describe what is in the table.

[image]

Since the description is long, the table to the right goes over the edge, even though the format `p` stops at the column heading called `time`. There should be nothing after that.

May be I could format `\endhead` text in multiple lines? How?

Here is example of another table, using same format `p` as the above, but because the `endhead` description is shorter, the last column does not overflow to the right

[image]

I just do not want to worry about the table description being too long and its affect on the actual table.

**edit**

I do use caption. But caption do not carry on each page,. It only show on first page of longtable. So if I put the description of the table in the caption, it will not show at top of next page. Only text that goes with `\endhead` carries over. Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}   
   \begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.2in}|p{1in}|p{0.1in}|}
   \caption{second order series method. Regular singular point. Difference not integer}\\\hline 
   \# & ODE & A \\\hline
   \endfirsthead
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename \thetable {} -- Continued from previous page}\\\hline 
   \# & ODE & A \\\hline
   \endhead \hline 
   \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{Continued on next page}\\\hline 
   \endfoot \hline 
   \endlastfoot      
   %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
 %first row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
   %second row
   1
   &2
   &3\\ \hline
\end{longtable}        
\end{document}
```

When compiled, first page shows

[image]

But next page do not have the caption description on it any more:

[image]

And that is the problem. I need the long description at top of each table on each page so I know what table I am looking at.

TL 2021 on Linux.

Comment: well a column heading has to fit over a column, how else would you know which column it is a heading for?  you can of course use multi-line cells such as `p` or nest a tabular or parbox, it doesn't have to be one line. The formatting is just the same as any other cell in the table.

Comment: but I thnk that isn't a column heading it is a continuation caption for the table so use `\caption{...}` not `\multicolumn`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I actually do use caption in my actual tables. I just did not use it in the MWE above. The problem is that caption only shows up on first page. If the longtable spans multiple pages, then the caption do not show up. Only `\endhead` text shows up at top of each page. I need that so I know which table I am looking at. I'll add an example.

Comment: no use caption again in the heading

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, I see. Like this? `\begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.2in}|p{1in}|p{0.1in}|}
   \caption{second order series method. Regular singular point. Difference not integer}\\\hline 
   \# & ODE & A \\\hline
   \endfirsthead
   \multicolumn{3}{c}{\tablename \thetable {} -- Continued from previous page}\\\hline 
   \caption{second order series method. Regular singular point. Difference not integer}\\\hline 
   \# & ODE & A \\\hline
   \endhead \hline 
   \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{Continued on next page}\\\hline 
   \endfoot \hline 
   \endlastfoot`

Comment: ... but now it looks strange.  screen shot. The `Table .1` is repeated twice.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjlVh.png)  I needed the `Continued from previous page` text also, so I know that this table is continued from last page. Caption alone do not say that?

Comment: longtable does have a manual with examples of captions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the original table size try

```
    \begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.2in}|p{1in}|p{0.1in}|}
        \caption{Second order series method. Regular singular point. Difference not integer.}\\
        \hline  
        \# & ODE & A \\\hline
        \endfirsthead
        \multicolumn{3}{@{}c@{}}{\parbox{\dimexpr1.3in+6\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}{\small\tablename~\thetable\ Second order series method. Regular singular point.  Difference not integer\\ {\footnotesize \emph{Continued from previous page}}\vspace*{1ex}}}\\\hline 
        \# & ODE & A \\\hline
        \endhead \hline 
        \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{\footnotesize \emph{Continued on next page}}\\\hline 
        \endfoot \hline 
        \endlastfoot      
        %first row
```

[image: a]
.

[image: c]

The `parbox` will do line breaks and allow `\\` inside. Its width is equal to the interior width of the table so it will not expand the table unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

One way to write your table is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
   \begin{longtable}[c]{|p{0.2in}|p{1in}|p{0.1in}|}
\caption{second order series method. Regular singular point. Difference not integer}    \\  
    \hline
   \# & ODE & A \\
   \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{second order series method. Regular singular point. Difference not integer (cont.)}    \\  
    \hline
   \# & ODE & A \\
   \endhead 
\multicolumn{3}{r @{}}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}    \\
   \endfoot 
   \endlastfoot
% table body
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline

 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
%
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
%
%
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
%
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
%
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
%
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
%
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

If you liked, you can instead `(cont.)` in the non first captions write `(continued from previous page)`

However, since your table is quite narrow, you can consider to have a table with 6 columns:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
   \begin{longtable}{|*{2}{p{0.2in}|p{1in}|p{0.1in}|}}
\caption{second order series method. Regular singular point. Difference not integer}    \\  
    \hline
\# & ODE & A    &   \# & ODE & A    \\
   \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{second order series method. Regular singular point. Difference not integer (Continued from the previous page)}                            \\  
    \hline
\# & ODE & A    &   \# & ODE & A    \\
   \endhead 
\multicolumn{6}{r @{}}{\footnotesize\textit{Continued on the next page}}    \\
   \endfoot 
   \endlastfoot
% 6 column table body
 1 & 2 & 3  &   1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3  &   1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3  &   1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3  &   1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
 1 & 2 & 3  &   1 & 2 & 3 \\  \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]